# Flow pathways during a flood event in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, waterways

I have a river and a field next to it (with its DEM). I want to determine the water's pathways in the field,  when the water in the river reaches a certain level , based on the DEM only.

I am thinking of using r.lake but it only uses one point as a seed?

Obviously a more precise hydraulic modelling of the river inundation is needed but I just want to have an idea of the pathways.

Answer (score 0):

By your own admission this is an exercise in futility.  What you need is a proper hydraulic model.  [Consider HEC-RAS](https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-ras/) (freeware).

Generating a detrended surface models (some call it a relative elevation model) might get you a vague idea of the flow of water at different water heights but again, this is not a peer-reviewed excepted practice filled with potential error.  [Here a link to detrending](https://dancoecarto.com/creating-rems-in-qgis-the-idw-method) in QGIS using IDW interpolation.

You don't ask for it but [here is a suit of  ArcGIS 10.7 toolbox tools](https://github.com/LummiGIS/Detrend-Surface-Models) using several different methods for detrending.  There is also an transect (IDW) tool for ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was asked to avoid using HEC-RAS due to time constraints and low stakes of the study so I am looking for a tool to get a rough idea of the water pathways in QGIS.